# Update a Git Submodule

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have two Git repositories. Both are websites. One is just hosted using GitHub Pages. The other is just a sample website I have been using to practice web design. I want to be able to link to the sample website from within my GitHub pages website.

I have the sample website as a submodule of my GitHub Pages website, so that now, I can visit:

```
www.githubpageswebsite.com/samplewebsite
```

and my sample website appears.

I want to make a change to the sample website and have tried making a commit in the sample website's repository and pushing it live but I don't see the change when I visit the above link.

How do I make a change to a repository and see the change where it is used as a submodule?

Comment: Possible caching problem?

Comment: No. Just checked and it isn't that!

Comment: Note that the caching could occur in at least two places: client side (i.e. web browser) or server side (i.e. the server software). But it might be that you need to connect to the sample website's git and tell it to checkout the commit/branch/tag you pushed.

Comment: I have committed it in the sample website's repository but I don't know how to make that change appear in the Pages website repository which is using it as subdirectory. Pretty sure it isn't to do with caching as in my Pages repository on Github, I can't see the change.

Comment: Is it a submodule of your main site? If that's the case, you may have to update the main site to point at the latest commit in the sample site (running `git status` in the parent should say something about new commits in the submodule). The parent of a submodule does not automatically update which commit it points to when you add a new commit the submodule.